# How to play vimeo private videos in my iOS Application

Tags: ios, vimeo-player, vimeo-ios

can you anyone help me how to play vimeo private videos . I have tried this https://github.com/vimeo/VimeoNetworking/ but it is always giving so many errors and pods not found .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a site for specific problems, not a *how to* site. Therefore, your question is unlikely to get any answers. Please describe your specific problem and document it in detail (e.g. by adding the error message, the source code). You might also want to look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm with you. There is no guidance for this, no details, it's just good luck and go. Someone needs to help answer this.

Comment: Did you found any work around?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to play private video in IOS application is that if you have a direct link to the video file then you can play that video anywhere.

- You can get video file link using API only if you have Pro Account.
- Or you can get the video file link from the video setting page if you have a Pro account.